# PHP: How to add a CSS text-align property to an already present inline style attribute of an element using simple_html_dom parser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, simple-html-dom

I have a string variable `$str` which contains HTML for a part of a page. I need to add the CSS property `text-align:justify` to all the `<p>` elements in the HTML (preferably using `simple_html_dom` parser).

Some of the `<p>` elements already have an inline `style` attribute, others don't. So I *can not* do something like

```
$str_html = str_get_html($str);
foreach ($str->find('p') as $p) {
  $p->style='text-align:justify;';
}
```

Because this will void any other styles already applied to the `<p>` element.

PS:- I can not use JQuery. I can use JS but will only use it as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not using the simple_htmL_dom parser but whats when you do this: `$p->style=$p->style + ' text-align:justify;';` So that the other style attributes won't be deleted.

Comment: My opinion is that you should do it in css directly instead. second alternative will by in javascript and the last will php php. I always try to avoid inline css if possible

Comment: @Bernd string concatenation operator in PHP is '.', not '+'

Comment: Huh. Forgot that this is no JS... lol thx @TML

Comment: Thank you everyone for the good suggestions, I find the answer by @FredericNault to be most suitable for my needs, so I'll use that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concatenate instead of re-assigning

```
$str_html = str_get_html($str);
foreach ($str->find('p') as $p) {
  $p->style .= '; text-align:justify;';
}
```